# Ideas on how to organize a project

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks, search, hierarchical

I know that questions that are mainly there to be discussed are not liked very much, but I still hope that you can think with me and give me some ideas. So thanks in advance to those of you, who are willing to help :)

I'm very new in Wordpress Development and I am facing some problems on how to organize all the files. For a better understandig I will split all the questions up.

#### Author rights

I'm developing a site for several authors and I only want them to have access to some pages. For example they shouldn't be able to see in the backend or edit the legal sites, the contact site, the homepage and so on.
As my site has static pages and a blog it isn't enough to restrict their access to the blog.

**So how can I have several types of static pages?**

#### Custom post types

My idea was to create some custom post types. One for all the sites they shouldn't edit, one for the *Practical courses* and one for the *Theory*. There it would be very easy to restrict access to the administrator only and it would clear up the backend, because the posts and pages would be sorted within their topics.

The problem I have with this is that I want the permalink structure *%postname%*. With my actual custom post types I wasn't able to get it working with that permalink. I always got a 404. Then I saw a plugin that allowed you to set the permalink structure to *%postname%* and it worked well, but now I was forced to have the slug in there too. And well, you maybe guessed it: I don't want it to be in there for some post types, while on others it would be great to have it. Remember: I just wanted to have a custom taxonomy for the restricted pages, like the contact page, the legals page and so on.

So at the moment, my permalinks would be something like this: `http://www.example.com/cpt-slug/contact`

I do want it to be `http://www.example.com/contact`

Now I saw a plugin that allows you to remove the slug from all the CPT, but for the practical courses and the theory I want to have them there, because it is more clear for the user.

**How can I remove the slug from a custom post type in the permalink structure *%postname%*, without removing the slug on all the CPTs?**

#### Custom taxonomies

Furthermore I would like to be able to have an "intelligent" search.
If a user enters to a site and searches something, he should only get results of that page and all the sub-pages of that page.

The hierarchy looks like this:

> Practical courses *(custom post type)*
>
> - Qualitative analysis *(parent taxonomy category)*
>
>   - Proofs for anions *(child taxonomy category)*
>
>     - Sulfate *(Post)*
>     - Phosphate *(Post)*
>     - Sulfide *(Post)*
>   - Proofs for cations *(child taxonomy category)*
> - Quantitative analysis *(parent taxonomy category)*
>
> Theory *(custom post type)*
>
> - Statistical thermodynamics *(parent taxonomy category)*
>
>   - Partition function *(Post)*
> - Schrödinger equation *(parent taxonomy category)*

You can see what my idea was on how to solve this problem. With these taxonomy categories, it should be easy to get the wanted intelligent search, **BUT** as far as I know WordPress has no function to display the taxonomy categories. And I have to be able to do so, because the pages *Practical courses*, *Qualitative Analysis*, *Proofs for Anions* are pages that only list their subpages. Oh, and before I forget, it isn't enough tho get a simple list with the different taxonomy categories, because we have thumbnails for each category. So I also need a method to set a thumbnail to these categories and than display them nicely on a page.

So on *Practical courses* you are able to click on *Qualitative Analysis*, *Quantitative analysis*, or other courses. You are then redirected to that page. That page, lets say *Qualitative Analysis* lists all the subpages of itself. So on that page you would be able to click on *Proofs for anions*, *Proof for cations* and so on. And now, when clicking on, lets say *Proofs for anions*, you will see a list of all the proofs. When clicking one, the post will open and you can read.

I'm coming back to the search for a second: If you search for something on the homepage, the whole database should be searched for that keyword and you'll get all the results. When searching for something on the *Practical courses* site, you should only get results that show up in this branch of the hierarchy. No results of the *Theory* should be shown. A search inside *Qualitative analysis* should only return results that are on that page or on *ALL* the subpages of itself. Same for all the other search forms.

So the search should never return results from parent pages.

---

---

So that were my questions with my ideas on how to solve them and the problelms I have with my solutions.

My main question to you, as more experienced WordPress developers, is the following: Are my ideas good, and should I do it like mentioned, or are there better ways to acieve what I'm trying to get? If my ideas a good, could you please help me around my problems?

Again, thank you very much!!

Comment: The main problems with this question: (A) It's a multitude of questions – you better separate them. (B) There is no code-research or effort to code things up yourself shown to answer anything your own. You might want to fix that. I am closing the question for now. We can reopen it when you reworked it and addressed the issues.

Answer (score 1):

You find it difficult to explain because it is still unclear what you are trying to achieve, even for you.

I think you should go over each of the obstacles/problems you face and formulate a clear question and ask again.

The way this is brought up, we could have millions of answer and a lot based on opinions and that is, like you said it, considered off topic here and for good reasons.

It's fairly easy to check a user role/capability and grant or restrict access to certain features, categories, settings, post type, etc. and etc. based on that.

You are saying that you don't want authors to modify `/legal` page, `/contact` page, etc. This looks like a job for `current_user_can( 'manage_options' )`  checks (only admins can manage options, not authors) and show, hide, redirect,  according to capabilities.

You say search form on page A should return page A results.  This looks like a job for a custom query maybe filtering by categories.

So again, I would dissect your project and ask questions related to specific obstacles you face so we could better assist you on those specific issues.  And remember that big sites and business are also using WordPress in complex and less complex situations, so a lot is possible when we our end objective is clear.

Comment: I just edited the question, if you want, cou can have a look. You may be right, that I'm also not completely aware on what I want, but I have some ideas up in my head. I didn't know that I can set restictions to single pages for some users. How do I do this?